# Are reportedly "bloated" index sizes a problem?

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, vacuum

I create a table with 1 million records, then I delete those records. (Common with some sort of processing list.)

```sql
CREATE TABLE example (id int PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO example SELECT generate_series(1, 1000 * 1000);
DELETE FROM example;
VACUUM example;
```

The index size remains at the same size as before deletion.

```sql
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(c.oid)) AS size
FROM pg_class c
WHERE oid = 'example_pkey'::regclass;
```

```
 size  
-------
 21 MB
(1 row)
```

Likewise, bloat-detection queries (e.g. [ioguix/pgsql-bloat-estimation](https://github.com/ioguix/pgsql-bloat-estimation/blob/master/btree/btree_bloat-superuser.sql)) identify this index as extremely bloated.

I don't care about the disk usage itself. **Will the performance of the index be affected by its large size?** Should I be running `REINDEX`?

Comment: [You two](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/295980/just-delete-50-000-000-of-rows-on-a-postgresql-table-and-db-still-very-slow) might want to talk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a substantial impact on the first few queries after the rows were deleted, because autovacuum hasn't finished processing the table yet and queries need to dig through a lot of index entries that belong to deleted rows.

However, these index scans will [mark the index entries as "dead"](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/killed-index-tuples/), and subsequent index scans will ignore them.

After that, and after `VACUUM` has finished, index scans will be alnost as fast as before.

Comment: I believe this is correct. Completely empty index pages don't hurt performance. Unfortunately, a lot of the scripts just look at the total physical index size, which never decreases without `REINDEX`/`VACUUM FULL`.  `pgstatindex` can give more accurate information, but it's slow as it has to read the index.